# How to programmatically display a select list label instead of the value?

Tags: forms, database

I created a select list box in the following format

```
Gender
1|Male
2|Female
```

I want to display the follwing information in a table but I am getting "1" for male and "2" for female.

Here is my code:

```
function display_results_submissions(){
$results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {users}");
$header = array( t('Name'), t('Mail'), t('Gender'),);

foreach($results as $result){
        $rows[] = array(

            $result->name,
            $result->mail,
            $result->gender,

            );
    }

    return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows'=>$rows));
}
```

I want to display Male or Female instead of "1" and "2". How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving the gender, the value that is stored in the database is the key and not the value. Hence, your database contained 1/2 instead of Male/Female. So, your query was right and only needed to format the key before storing in `rows[]`.

```
function display_results_submissions(){
  $results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {users}");
  $header = array(t('Name'), t('Mail'), t('Gender'));
  foreach($results as $result){
    $gender = $result->gender == '1' ? t('Male') : t('Female');
    $rows[] = array(
      $result->name,
      $result->mail,
      $gender,
    );
  }

  return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use entity_metadata_wrapper because when the select label changes you don't have to change your code.

Following lines will do what you want:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $result->uid);
$gender = $wrapper->field_user_gender->label();
```

So your code would look like:

```
function display_results_submissions(){
  $results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {users}");
  $header = array(t('Name'), t('Mail'), t('Gender'));
  foreach($results as $result){
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $result->uid);
    $gender = $wrapper->field_user_gender->label();
    $rows[] = array(
      $result->name,
      $result->mail,
      $gender,
    );
  }

  return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
}
```

There is a good blog post at http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/entity-metadata-wrapper

Comment: Don't forget to replace "field_user_gender" with your field name :)

Comment: I liked you solution. I should start using entity metadata wrappers.